# How to use Entity Framework witk Sharepoint Custom Timer Job?

Tags: entity-framework, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, connection-string, sharepoint-timer-job

I developed a SharePoint Custom Timer Job which reaches SQL Server by Entity Framework. So normally EF uses SharePoint application's web.config AppSettings to get the ConnectionString it needed. But, in this case, where Custom Timer Job reaches SQL Server via EF, it gives me

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

It is obvious that it can't read ConnectionString value from configuration.

**QUESTION:**

Do you guys know where is this SharePoint Customer Timer Job's configuration file is?
SharePoint Administration application web.config? machine.config? Feature.xml of Feature?

If it doesn't read this info from a config file, what should I do to access ConnectionString of EF? Use properties of Custom Timer Job to persist ConnectionString information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SP job timer is executed by the SP timer job window service. The exe is Owstimer.exe located in the bin folder. You can add to or created Owstimer.exe.config so that your custom job can read from it.

Comment: So I changed it as, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration> <runtime> <connectionStrings> <add name="Holiday_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.HolidayDataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.HolidayDataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.HolidayDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=CSNDEVPOOL06\DEVSQL;Initial Catalog=HUMANIST90;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> </connectionStrings> </runtime> </configuration> ` but still same error.

Comment: And does it work? You will need to restart the service for the config to take effect

Comment: Oh I noticed you use integrated security. When job is started by the timer it will take whatever the process owner for the service (Owstimer) which is usually network service or local service. This acc prob can't auth to your SQL server. I suggest create and acc and use it in your conn string or set the service to launch as a specific user

Comment: restarted the Timer Service and IIS. Deployed Custom Timer Job solution again and still same error exists.

Comment: The SharePoint 2010 Timer service LogOnAs user is a domain user and it has necessary SQL server permissions on both machine and DB. Sorry to bother you for this small prob, but you know it is pain in the a** for me right now. Also, it is 1am in local time:)

Comment: Sorry Melih I don't have anyore thoughts on what may cause your problem. Try trace logging your code and also te exceptions and see if the problem is still wig EF and not other permission error. If this box is not your regular dev machine try connecting to the SQL instance manually to ensure all the firewall and port bypassing are set correctly. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Timer job is not hosted by web application. It is running in separate process - owstimer.exe. Locate the file on your server and simply create owstimer.exe.config file (if it doesn't exists) and place necessary configuration to that file.

Comment: I gave the necessary configuration for EF in the file that you mentioned at Fadrian Sudaman's post's comment, but still same issue continues. Do you have an advice?

Comment: Why do you have `connectionString` under `runtime` element? That should be directly under `configuration` element.